# I cannot retrieve dynamic link from firebase through my application as pendingdynamiclinkdata is null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, deep-linking

I am trying to retrieve the **deeplink** URL from **firebase** but always shows me null.

i have added below code in manifest and i have also tried with the short dynamic URL i.e. https://example555.page.link/y6N7 but still its show me null.

```
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data
                android:host="example555.page.link"
                android:scheme="https"
                 />

        </intent-filter>
```

Here is my code of retrieving dynamic link :

```
             FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
             .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
             .addOnSuccessListener(this, new 
             OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
            @Override
             public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData 
             pendingDynamicLinkData) {
              Uri deepLink = null;

                if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                    deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                }
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so after banging my head for so many hours i found a solution which helped me in getting the solution :

so ill start from beginning :
1. create a dynamic link.
2. add following code to your manifest

```
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data
            android:host="example555.page.link"
            android:scheme="https"/>

    </intent-filter>
```

3. add this code in you Main activity :

   ```
          FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
           mFirebaseAnalytics=FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);

           FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
           .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
           .addOnSuccessListener(this, new 
            OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
               @Override
               public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                   // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                   Uri deepLink = null;

                   if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                       deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();

                       Log.w("deepLink", "" + deepLink);
                  String cn=String.valueOf(deepLink.getQueryParameters("utm_campaign"));
                       String cm = String.valueOf(deepLink. getQueryParameters("utm_medium"));
                       String cs = String.valueOf(deepLink.getQueryParameters("utm_source"));

                       if (cs != null && cn != null) {
                           Bundle params = new Bundle();
                           params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CAMPAIGN, cn);
                           params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.MEDIUM, cm);
                           params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SOURCE, cs);

                           mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.CAMPAIGN_DETAILS, params);
                           mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.APP_OPEN, params);
                       }


                   }
               }
           })
           .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
               @Override
               public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                   Log.w("TAG", "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
               }
           });
   ```
4. now its time to test your application:
   google search your url i.e example555.page.link
   after that it will redirect you to application and you fill and your out put.
   if this works than thankyou.

Comment: aslo gives permission of internet.